# Plotting timestamp data using Javascript

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I have an array of timestamps like `[1485343314150, 1485343314150, 1485343314150, 1485343314300, 1485343314300, 1485343314400,1485343314450]`.
Here there are 3 values for `1485343314150`, 2 values for `1485343314300` and 1 value each for `1485343314400` and `1485343314450`

So while plotting on the graph

X = [1485343314150,1485343314300,1485343314400,1485343314450]

Y = [3,2,1,1]

I need a way to represent these X and Y such that Xs values are converted to a human readable datetime like 24-February 5:25 PM.

Can it be done via `Chart.js` or `amCharts`? I searched but couldn't find anything.

Comment: [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) has nice date formatting functions, and I think amCharts at least has its own formatting functions available - in any case, any chart library should be able to convert the timestamps into formatted dates

Comment: Please see this : https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/simulating-date-based-axis-xy-chart-using-labelfunction-timestamps-values/                                                                                                           "labelFunction": function(value) {
      var date = new Date(value);
      return AmCharts.formatDate(date, "MMM DD");
    }

Answer (score 0):

In AmCharts you can set [`parseDates`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#parseDates) to `true` in your `categoryAxis` (which is the same as the X axis) if you're using a serial chart (line, smoothed line, or column). AmCharts' XY chart can also handle dates as well by setting one of the valueAxes' [`type`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#type) to `"date"`, but the chart types available are limited to lines/bullets

When you enable parseDates, the chart will automatically format them to use readable date strings. You can adjust the format by specifying your own [`dateFormats`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#dateFormats) array in the categoryAxis. You can find more information on that [here](http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/formatting-dates/).

Here's an example using a serial chart. Your data frequency is in incrments of milliseconds, so I set the categoryAxis' [`minPeriod`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#minPeriod) to accommodate:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [{
    "timestamp": 1485343314150,
    "value": 3
  },{
    "timestamp": 1485343314300,
    "value": 2
  },{
    "timestamp": 1485343314400,
    "value": 1
  },{
    "timestamp": 1485343314450,
    "value": 1
  }],
  "graphs": [{
    "bullet": "round",
    "type": "smoothedLine",
    "valueField": "value"
  }],
  "categoryField": "timestamp",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "parseDates": true,
    "minPeriod": "fff"
  }
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

You can further format the axis' output through the `dateFormats` property as mentioned before. In this scenario, you'll want to change the string in the `fff` period. Depending on the amount of data, you may need to change the larger periods as well.